# Filtering nodes related to specific nodes in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can one filter all nodes connected to some set of nodes efficiently?

I have this for now:

```
MATCH (:City { Id: 10 })<-[:LIVES_IN]-(p:Person),
p-[:KNOWS]->(:Person { Name: 'John' }),
p-[:KNOWS]->(:Person { Name: 'Mark' }),
p-[:KNOWS]->(:Person { Name: 'Jane' }),
p-[:KNOWS]->(:Person { Name: 'Mary' })
RETURN p
```

And this does what I want but it's very slow. It takes about 900ms on a database with approx. 500 nodes labeled as Person.

The problem I want to solve is even bigger

```
MATCH (:City { Id: 10 })<-[:LIVES_IN]-(p:Person)-[:HAS_ITEM]->(i:Item),
p-[:KNOWS]->(:Person { Name: 'John' }),
p-[:KNOWS]->(:Person { Name: 'Mark' }),
p-[:KNOWS]->(:Person { Name: 'Jane' }),
p-[:KNOWS]->(:Person { Name: 'Mary' })
RETURN i, count(p)
```

This query finds people that have items and for each item, it returns the count of all people that have that item and also know certain people. This query never finishes (or I didn't wait long enough).

When I remove the 'know certain people' part, the query finishes in about 400ms.

```
MATCH (:City { Id: 10 })<-[:LIVES_IN]-(p:Person)-[:HAS_ITEM]->(i:Item),
RETURN i, count(p)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reordering it to minimize the number of results it has to search through at a time. Something like this--if knows groups are smaller than the number of people that live in the city and the number of people who have items, then this might even be better (if the people who have items is pretty low, can swap it around):

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(:Person { Name: 'John' }) // start with john's friends
WITH p
MATCH (:City { Id: 10 })<-[:LIVES_IN]-(p)-[:HAS_ITEM]->(i:Item) // only friends that live in city 10 and have the item...
WITH p, i
MATCH p-[:KNOWS]->(:Person { Name: 'Mark' })
WITH p, i
MATCH p-[:KNOWS]->(:Person { Name: 'Jane' })
WITH p, i
MATCH p-[:KNOWS]->(:Person { Name: 'Mary' })
RETURN i, count(p)
```

Also, make sure you have an index on `:Person(Name)` and `:City(Id)`

Comment: With statement did the trick. Putting `MATCH (:City { Id: 10 })<-[:LIVES_IN]-(p)-[:HAS_ITEM]->(i:Item)` as the last statement gave even better performance. I think it's because there are a lot of items connected to people and reducing the number of people before traversing to items helps. Queries are now sub 100ms and execution time drops even more when more `p-[:KNOWS]->(someone)` filters are added. Thanks!